# Micro Application Phalcon "/" route redirect to not Not found

Tags: routes, phalcon

I started to learn Phalcon Micro Application and generated the project using phalcon dev tools. 
I am facing problem for routes.

Below are the codes for .htaccess and my routes, but whenever i go to any other root other than "/" , it works, but for "/" route it goes to not found route.

Default .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
 RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Public folder .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

My routes in public/index.php are:

```
$app->get('/', function () {
  echo "home";
});

$app->notFound(function(){
  echo "not Found";
});
```

My project is in vagrant VM with the below url

```
http://192.168.50.4/api/
```

Can you please help me

Really Appreciate

Thanks,

Comment: what u get when http://192.168.50.4?

Comment: Hi Fazal, i get default page of Vagrant Box. My project is in api folder.

Answer (score 1):

Nice choice of framework!

Try to change

```
$app->get('/api', function () {
```

I sugest you use handlers, an then you cand add a prefix to your application routes, see the documentation below:

https://docs.phalconphp.com/pt/latest/reference/micro.html#using-controllers-as-handlers

Comment: Thanks Wesley, i will try and ask for further help.

Answer (score 1):

Or:

`$di->set('url', function () {
        $url = new Url();
        $url->setBaseUri('/api/');
        return $url;
    });`